# How can I convert a 3D image by using numpy when I am getting "The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array" error?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am working with NUAA dataset and trying to classify real and spoof dataset. and now I am getting that input is 3 dimensional. I couldn't convert it 2D.

```
class to_LBP():
  '''class to calculate LBP'''

  def __init__(self, n_points_radius, method):
    self.n_points=n_points_radius
    self.method=method       
    self.channels=len(self.n_points) 
    self.kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
    

  def  __call__(self, sample):       
    w, h=sample.size
    temp=np.zeros((self.channels, w, h))
    # print("sample", sample)
    # print(type(sample)) 
    image= np.array(sample)
    # print(image)   
    print("image.shape",image.shape) 
    image=cv2.filter2D(image, -1, self.kernel)    
    for idx, values in enumerate(self.n_points):             
      lbp=local_binary_pattern(image, values[0], values[1], self.method)              
      temp[idx]=lbp      
    return (temp,  image)
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible code sample. Please assume we don't know what is NUAA dataset, and we don't know how to get 3D image from the dataset.

Comment: [mre] required. especially the traceback.